# Automatically reference the foreign key of table with a primary key other table in different Schema?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

I have two schema `A` and `B` with each having two tables `p` and `q` in Amazon Redshift.

`A.p` is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE A.p (
   id int8 PRIMARY KEY,
   val int8
)
```

and `A.q` as

```
CREATE TABLE A.q (
   id int8 PRIMARY KEY,
   id2 int8,
   FOREIGN KEY(id2) REFERENCES A.p(id)
)
```

And similarly `B.p` as

```
CREATE TABLE B.p (
   id int8 PRIMARY KEY,
   val int8
)
```

And `B.q` as

```
CREATE TABLE B.q (
   id int8 PRIMARY KEY,
   id2 int8,
   FOREIGN KEY(id2) REFERENCES B.p(id)
)
```

Why does Amazon Redshift automatically map the reference `B.q(id2)` to `A.p(id)`?
And what can be done to avoid it?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by "*Amazon Redshift maps a reference*"? Any example that behaves wrong?

Comment: Well, Amazon Redshift does not enforce Foreign key constraints in the database.  Having Foreign Key helps in Query planning & Object permissions.

Is that possible that B.q have some value which accidentally matches A.p? 

You could drop table A.q, & A.p. if any relationship established to B.q then Drop command will fail for dependency graph.

Comment: If i make the both the schema with same tables names and same column names Redshift automatically does the cross referencing

Comment: means it automatically assigns the foreign key relationship between the tables B.q and A.p